# Memory Error of map.bluemarble() in Python Basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

When I run `my_map.bluemarble()`, I got this error message, while if I delete the `my_map.bluemarble()`, the program works fine!
What shoud I do ?

Thanks!

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Workspace\after201512\2015CCN2\plot_CCN_map.py", line 54, in <module>
    my_map.bluemarble()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.py", line 3982, in bluemarble
    return self.warpimage(image='bluemarble',scale=scale,**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.py", line 4144, in warpimage
    self._bm_lons,self._bm_lats,nx,ny,returnxy=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.py", line 2966, in transform_scalar
    datout = interp(datin,lons,lats,lonsout,latsout,checkbounds=checkbounds,order=order,masked=masked)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.py", line 4960, in interp
    (1.-delx)*dely*datain[yip1,xi] + \
MemoryError`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap.bluemarble) states that it uses a lot of memory, but you can use the `scale` parameter to downsample the image:

```
my_map.bluemarble(scale=0.5)
```